Enviar json a API mediante Ajax para obtener un response para rellenar un Datatable
La api está diseñada de forma que si envio un json lo toma como filtro. Y si no envio json entonces me devuelve la tabla completa. El filtro está diseñado para ir en el body, Y cuando lo pruebo en Thunder Cliente o en Postman este funciona bien, pero cuando quiero acceder a él desde codigo me devuelve como si no le estuviera mandando ningun filtro, me devuelve la tabla completa. El código que tengo para acceder a la api es el siguiente:
    let idUsuEncrip = localStorage.getItem("sesion-usuario-idencriptado");
    let token = localStorage.getItem("sesion-usuario-apptoken");
    let tenant_ = localStorage.getItem("sesion-usuario-tenant");
    
    var filtros = { nombre: "Mateo"};   //este es el filtro

   var data= JSON.stringify(filtros);     //paso el filtro a json

   var tab = $("#kt_datatable_column_rendering").DataTable({

    ajax: {
        type: "post",
        url: 'https://api-dev.areea.cloud/v4/private/dt_usuarios/v2/get_usuarios_by_filtro' + "?app_idusuario_encriptado=" + encodeURIComponent(idUsuEncrip) + "&app_token=" + encodeURIComponent(token) + "&tenant=" + encodeURIComponent(tenant_),
        dataType: 'json',          
        dataSrc: '',
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(filtros)
        
    },

    columns: [{
            data: 'id'
        },
        {
            data: 'login'
        },
        {
            data: 'password'
        },
        {
            data: 'numdocidentificacion'
        },
        {
            data: 'nombre'
        },
        {
            data: 'apellidos'
        },
        {
            data: 'app_token'
        }
    ]

});

Por algún motivo no reconoce el json que paso al ajax. Sabe alguien como debería de pasarlo?
Lo que espero es que la api me devuelva un registro de acuerdo con el filtro que he implementado.

algun error en consola??

No. Devuelve todos los datos de la tabla, tal como se comporta la api en el Thunder Client en el caso en que no envío filtros, es decir que no ve el Json que mando en data:JSON.stringify(filtros)
